# 802.11ac network setup slowed down

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, 802.11ac

So, for a long time been running on a dd-wrt router, connecting at low 10Mb/s speeds wirelessly, so I decided to give a try to a 802.11AC. So I bought the hardware, set it up, but I'm not happy with the connection speed I'm getting, which is about 80Mb/s

What I did was buying this Tenda 802.11 AC router **(img 1)**

Then I bought 2 of these USB 802.11 AC network adapters (EDUDP) which installs Ralink drivers **(img 2)**

The first issue I encounter, is windows connecting as radio-type 802.11n instead of 802.11ac **(img 3 and 4)**

The 802.11ac protocol says you can connect up to 800Mb/s, but the most I'm getting from this setup is about 80Mb/s. I tested this speed using Windows NTTTCP tool, it's a network testing tool, the measured speed was between the 2 computers with the 802.11AC network adapters, going through the new router. If I run the same tests cross wiring both computers on their ethernet adapters, I would get close enough to 1000Mb/s which is the max speed you can reach on Gigabit adapters.

The 80Mb/s is while connecting through a 5G network. I can also connect on a 2.4G network, the most speed I get in such case is 40Mb/s, if I fallback to the dd-wrt router and run the same test, all I get is 10Mb/s.

Here are the pictures:  [802.11 AC setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhAXo.jpg)

Is it possible that the EDUDP are crappy Chinesse adapters ? What else could I do to troubleshot / enhance this ? Honestly I feel like the setup is right, and I can't tweak it to perform any better, but I also feel like if I run and buy expensive 802.11AC adapters the results wont be any different.

Look forward to hearing your thoughts !

Agustin.

### UPDATE:

Followed Spiff's suggestion, changed the channel to 80mhz. It didn't really mean a difference in the test results, here is a snapshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnp15.jpg
You can see a spike on the network traffic during the tests, but the most I get is an average of 7,000,000 bytes per second, which is about 6.7 MegaBytes/s or 53 Megabits/s

Is it possible there is such a big difference between the advertised speeds and the real speeds ?
Am I doing something terribly wrong ?

I think I should explore the wi-fi alliance page and think of redoing the setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Fix your AP configuration to use 80MHz channels**
Note that getting that top PHY rate requires using 80MHz-wide channels. Your screenshot of your AP configuration shows that you've limited it to 20MHz-wide channels, which limits your PHY rate to 156Mbps. Getting 80Mbps of TCP/IPv4 throughput with a 156Mbps PHY rate is actually decent. If you fix your AP configuration to use 80MHz-wide channels, you should be able to get the 867Mbps PHY rate, and TCP/IPv4 throughputs of perhaps 500 or 600Mbps.

**Don't trust that equipment**
That said, all that equipment looks pretty sketchy. Consider checking the [Wi-Fi Alliance's website](http://wi-fi.org/) to find equipment that has actually been certified 802.11ac by the Wi-Fi Alliance.

Note also that the equipment you've bought doesn't even do the top 802.11ac rates that have been shipping in products since 2012 (well, in reliable form since 2013), which is 1300Mbps using 3 spatial streams. The stuff you bought only does 2 spatial streams, so it can only do 867Mbps signaling (PHY rate).

Comment: Any further thought after my last question update ? Thanks ^_^